# How can I make my site fit iPhone's screens?

Tags: iphone, web, screen-resolution

My site (linearedge.com) doesn't fit iphone's screens. I've tried with a lot of different combinations of viewport meta properties and nothing has worked.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try styling your website using CSS [@media queries](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) to make it responsive. For example the one below, basically means that if your screen is smaller than 739px, then set the width of #container to 200px. If you adjust the size of containers in your website accordingly it should fit.

```
 @media only screen and (max-width:739px) {
      #container { width:200px; }
          ...
 }
```